# Trying to receive Installation-validation postback using SKAdNetwork

Tags: ios, skadnetwork

I have an iOS app publisehd on App Store and to advertise the app, i am using App Store Connect Campaign Links on my campaigns, like email campaign, Facebook and Instagram campaigns.

I would like to know which campaign is going good.

For that, i have done the below two steps to track app installation and campaign details, like Source of installation.

> Set NSAdvertisingAttributionReportEndpoint in info.plist

> SKAdNetwork.updatePostbackConversionValue(0) in didFinishLaunching

Also, enabled the server endoint https://<MyDomain.com>/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/ to accept HTTP POST messages.

Now, i am trying to test the postback from TestFlight build of my app.

But i am getting the below error in console.

> Error setting developer pingback domain for app: <MY_APP_ID>, error: (null), result: 0

Am i doing anything wrong? Please advise,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I am getting the following messages on console

> Registering install attribution pingback

> Registered pingback for app: [MyAppId]

> Error setting developer pingback domain for app: [MyAppId], error: (null), result: 0

But server did not receive postbacks. Server is not even pinged, i think.

Thank you.